# create a retention table base on games played

Tags: sql, sql-server, retention

**Situation:**

I have a table with three columns:

- date
- game
- user_id

From that table I need to create a retention table that will ultimately look like this:

**Output:**

```
+------------+-------------+------+-------------+------+------+-------+
|    date    |    game     | day0 |    day1     | day3 | day7 | day10 |
+------------+-------------+------+-------------+------+------+-------+
| 2019-01-01 | fifa        |  100 | % of day  0 |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-01 | nba         |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-01 | battlefield |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-02 | fifa        |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-02 | battlefield |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-03 | fifa        |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| 2019-01-03 | nba         |  100 |             |      |      |       |
| ...        |             |      |             |      |      |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-------------+------+------+-------+
```

day0 is 100 if at least one person played the game

day1 is the proportion of distinct users that came back one 1 or 2 days later

day3 is the proportion of distinct users that came back between 3 and 6 days later.

and so on...

if you plot the numbers , it should give you a non linear decreasing curve.

**Logic:**

*(see sample data below)*

The skeleton I built so far looks like this:

```
;WITH 
    baseDate AS (
        SELECT
         'target_date' AS [key_name]
        ,CAST('2019-01-01' AS date) AS [key_value]
        ),
durationDate AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,0,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,2,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,3,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,4,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,5,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,6,key_value) AS target_date FROM baseDate WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
)
    select 
        dd.target_date
        , play.game 
        , play.[count]/play.count *100 as day0
    from durationDate as dd
    left join (
        select t1.date, t1.game, COUNT(distinct t1.user_id) as [count]
        from #t1 t1
        group by t1.date, t1.game
        ) as play on dd.target_date=play.[date]
```

I am probably missing another base table for columns day1, day3, day7 such as:

```
durationDateColumn AS (
        SELECT 
              DATEADD(DAY,0,key_value) AS day1
            , DATEADD(DAY,1,key_value) AS day2
            , DATEADD(DAY,2,key_value) AS day3
            , DATEADD(DAY,3,key_value) AS day4
            , DATEADD(DAY,4,key_value) AS day5
            , DATEADD(DAY,5,key_value) AS day6
            , DATEADD(DAY,6,key_value) AS day7
        FROM baseDate
        WHERE [key_name] = 'target_date'
    )
```

unless there is a more efficient way of doing this.

**Sample Data:**

```
drop table if exists #t1
create table #t1 ([date] date, [game] varchar (20),[user_id] bigint)
insert into #t1 values 
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',11),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',14),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',14),
('2019-01-04', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-04', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-08', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',11),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',14),
('2019-01-02', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-02', 'nba',14),
('2019-01-04', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-08', 'nba',13)
```

Comment: Not sure how the curve is decreasing when suppose on the 6th day more users returned then on the 2nd day.

Comment: usually this is what retention looks like , my sample data is not representative, i'll change it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the date and following dates data, compute number of days and count of users. Pivot by the number of days using conditional aggregation.

```
create table #t1 ([date] date, [game] varchar (20),[user_id] bigint);

insert into #t1 values 
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',11),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-01', 'fifa',14),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-02', 'fifa',14),
('2019-01-04', 'fifa',12),
('2019-01-04', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-08', 'fifa',13),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',11),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-01', 'nba',14),
('2019-01-02', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-02', 'nba',14),
('2019-01-04', 'nba',13),
('2019-01-08', 'nba',13);

select [date], [game] 
  , 100.0 day0
  , cast(100.0 * (0.0 + sum(case ret when 1 then n else 0 end)) / sum(case ret when 0 then n end) as decimal(5,2)) day1
  , cast(100.0 * (0.0 + sum(case ret when 2 then n else 0 end)) / sum(case ret when 0 then n end) as decimal(5,2)) day2
  , cast(100.0 * (0.0 + sum(case ret when 3 then n else 0 end)) / sum(case ret when 0 then n end) as decimal(5,2)) day3
  , cast(100.0 * (0.0 + sum(case ret when 4 then n else 0 end)) / sum(case ret when 0 then n end) as decimal(5,2)) day4
  -- .. more days
from (
    select t1.[date], t1.[game], Datediff(dd, t1.[Date], t2.[Date]) ret, count(distinct t1.[user_id]) n
    from #t1 t1
    left join #t1 t2
        on t1.game = t2.game and t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.date <= t2.date
    group by t1.[date], t1.[game], Datediff(dd, t1.[Date], t2.[Date])
) evt
group by [date], [game]
order by [date], [game];
```

Output

```
date    game    day0    day1    day2    day3    day4
2019-01-01  fifa    100.0   75.00   0.00    50.00   0.00
2019-01-01  nba     100.0   66.67   0.00    33.33   0.00
2019-01-02  fifa    100.0   0.00    66.67   0.00    0.00
2019-01-02  nba     100.0   0.00    50.00   0.00    0.00
2019-01-04  fifa    100.0   0.00    0.00    0.00    50.00
2019-01-04  nba     100.0   0.00    0.00    0.00    100.00
2019-01-08  fifa    100.0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
2019-01-08  nba     100.0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```